# Using PDEs to find a perpendicular set of curves to a vector field

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, vector-fields

So I was interested in finding the set of curves which are perpendicular to this Vector field
$$\vec F(x,y) = (x-y,x+y)$$
Lets say the perpendicular curves can be expressed as level curves of the function $G(x,y)$. We know that the normal of the perpendicular curves is parallel to $\vec F(x,y)$. The general expression for finding perpendicular surfaces in 3 dimensions would be
$$\nabla G\times\vec F = 0$$
Of course since we're only operating in two dimensions, the "cross product" is simply a scalar and the when applied to the given $\vec F$ the following equation results
$$(x-y)\frac{\partial G}{\partial y} = (x+y)\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}$$

This is where I stop. My only known method for solving PDEs is to assume it a product of two single variable functions, rearrange the functions of each variable to their respective side, and solve two ODEs. This isn't possible here so I am not sure what to do. Can anyone solve, recommend tips, or point me to any sources?

Answer (score 2):

$$ (x+y)\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}+(y-x)\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}=0$$
The Charpit-Lagrange system of characteristic equations is :
$$\frac{dx}{x+y}=\frac{dy}{y-x}=\frac{dG}{0}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from $\frac{dx}{x+y}=\frac{dy}{y-x}$ . 
This is an homogeneous ODE easy to solve : change of variable $y(x)=xu(x)$. The solution is:
$$\ln(x^2+y^2)+2\arctan(\frac{y}{x})=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from $\frac{dG}{0}\neq 0$ which implies $G=c_2$.

From the relationship $\Phi(c_1,c_2)=0$ where $\Phi$ is an arbitrary function, or equivalently $c_2=F(c_1)$ where $F$ is an arbitrary function :
$$G(x,y)=F\left(\ln(x^2+y^2)+2\arctan(\frac{y}{x}) \right)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function which could be determined insofar some boundary conditions where specified.

Note : Don't confuse this notation of function $F$ with the notation $\vec F(x,y)$ used in the wording of the question.

Comment: Thank you so much. What kind of boundary condition would you need to determine $F$?

Comment: Boundary conditions are necessary in a general context of solving PDE. I suppose that you only want the "level curves" where $G(x,y)=$constant. Then doesn't mater $F$ since the function of a constant is a constant. $$\ln(x^2+y^2)+2\arctan(y/x)=\text{constant}$$

Comment: I understand that. I'm asking what kind of information you would need in order to determine a specific $F$.

Comment: They are several kind of boundary conditions. For example : a specified relationship between $x$ and $y$ along a specified line. But depending on the context, the condition might also  involve specified relationship with partial derivative, or something else. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BoundaryConditions.html .

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_value_problem